# ApacheCamel: readLock = idempotent vs readLock = rename

Tags: apache-camel

In my application, we have multiple nodes for sharing File system. So in this case,idempotentRepository required for Locking mechanism.

**Question:**
In Apache Camel why "readLock = idempotent" is working only for File component but  not for FTP?

> **readLock: idempotent** not compatible for FTP, its compatible only for File component.

```
<from uri="ftp://XXX:xxxxxx@localhost/var/opt/irs/message?delete=true&amp;readLock=idempotent&amp;idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepo&amp;readLockLoggingLevel=WARN&amp;shuffle=true" />
```

> **readLock: rename is compatible for FTP**

and I achieved with this

```
<from uri="ftp://XXX:xxxxxx@localhost/var/opt/irs/message?delete=true&amp;readLock=rename&amp;idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepo&amp;readLockLoggingLevel=WARN&amp;shuffle=true" />
```

I would like to know the reson behind it.

Can anybody explain the reson behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can clearly see in the document [here](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html). It states
**idempotent --  Camel 2.16 (only file component) is for using a idempotentRepository as the read-lock.**

You can achieve this for ftp by doing something like this

```
 from("ftps://{{ftp.username}}@{{ftp.host}}/{{ftp.importDirectory}}?password="
            + "{{ftp.password}}&readLock=changed&move={{ftp.processed}}"
            + "&moveFailed={{ftp.failed}}"
            + "&securityProtocol=SSL&execProt=P&execPbsz=0&passiveMode=true")
           .idempotentConsumer(header("camelFileAbsolutePath"),
                MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository(200))
            .to("bean:ftpConsumer?method=consumeMethod")
```

Comment: Thanks its really a nice explanation, I also achieved by doing this                                              <from uri="ftp://XXX:xxxxxx@localhost/var/opt/irs/message?delete=true&amp;readLock=rename&amp;idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepo&amp;readLockLoggingLevel=WARN&amp;shuffle=true" />